# Setting the filetype in ASP.net fileupload

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, file-upload

Is it possible to limit the asp.net fileupload dialog to view only XML files?
(Filer, .xml only)

Note: Not to check whether the extension is .xml, but to actually only let the user view xml files in the dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot set a filter for the file browser dialog - you have to use JavaScript or server-side validation for extension.

**Upd.**
You can use RegularExpression validator with the following regex string:

```
@"(.*?)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$"
```